# Apollo R: Error in apollo_estimate(apollo_beta, apollo_fixed, apollo_probabilities, : Not proceeding with estimation

Tags: r, model, binary, apollo, estimation

when using the Apollo package to estimate a binary choice model I get the error: "apollo_estimate(apollo_beta, apollo_fixed, apollo_probabilities,  : Not proceeding with estimation!"
I have checked my code and looked into a few forums to try and find where my mistake is but I can't seem to find it. I posted the code below hoping that someone can help me.
Thank you in advance!!

-Irini

'''

```
rm(list=ls())
install.packages("apollo")
library(apollo)
database <- read.csv2("Dutch_daten.csv")
str(database)
database$cost <- as.numeric(as.character(database$cost))
database$ivtt <- as.numeric(as.character(database$ivtt))
database$rpovt <- as.numeric(as.character(database$rpovt))

### Initialise code
apollo_initialise()

### Set core controls
apollo_control= list(
  modelName="ApolloNetherlands_Exc",
  modelDescr="BinaryChoiceModel",
  indivID = "idx.alt"
)

### Define model parameters for specification 0

apollo_beta <- c(b0_rail =0,
                 b1_cost = 0,
                 b2_time = 0)
apollo_fixed = c()

### GROUP AND VALIDATE INPUTS
apollo_inputs = apollo_validateInputs()

### DEFINE MODEL AND LIKELIHOOD FUNCTION
apollo_probabilities=function(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs, functionality="estimate"){
  
  
  apollo_attach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs)
  on.exit(apollo_detach(apollo_beta, apollo_inputs))
  
  
  P = list()
  
  
  V <- list()
  
  V[['rail']] <- b0_rail + b1_cost*cost+ b2_time*(ivtt+rpovt)
  V[['car']] <- b1_cost*cost+ b2_time*(ivtt+rpovt)
  
  mnl_settings = list(
    alternatives = c(car=1, rail=2),
    avail = list(car=1, rail=1),
    choiceVar = idx.alt,
    V = V
  )
  
  P[["model"]]=apollo_mnl(mnl_settings, functionality)
  
  
  P = apollo_panelProd(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
  
  P = apollo_prepareProb(P, apollo_inputs, functionality)
  return(P)
}

# ################################################################# #
#### MODEL ESTIMATION                                            ####
# ################################################################# #

model = apollo_estimate(apollo_beta, apollo_fixed, apollo_probabilities, apollo_inputs)
```

Comment: Were there any other log messages before *Not proceeding with estimation!*?

Comment: No, there where no other messages except of that one.

Comment: You have specified your choice indicator and individual indicator to be the same. I would say that is the most likely culprit for why your model fails. Apologies for reading this late and I hope you managed to get your model estimated.